# OSX El Capitan localhost webserver stopped working after changing file permissions and restarting

Tags: localhost, apache2, osx-elcapitan

I broke the apache2 webserver in el capitan.

Was trying to assign read write execute to all files within `/Library/Webserver/Documents/`

the two commands that broke localhost are:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Library/Webserver/Documents/

sudo apachectl restart
```

How to get it working again? When i try an load http://localhost - It is just a spinning wheel after

Does it have to do with file permissions?

Comment: El Capitan is EOL, plus `sudo chmod -R 777` is almost always the wrongest thing to do.

Comment: Yes sir. +1 for the smack-talk. But to fix the problem, what is my best option to recover the damage?